# Show message and reset form PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

I configured a phpmailer to send info from a form and works perfectly but when sends the mail show a blank page with the message: "Thank you for contacting us, one of our associates will contact you soon"
Here is the sending code:

```
 try {
        if ($_POST['name'] != '' && $_POST['email'] != '' && $_POST['message'] != '') {
        $mail->Body    = $messaje;
        } 

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) { //Catch all kinds of bad addressing
        throw new phpmailerAppException($e->getMessage());
    }

        if(!$mail->send()) {
           echo 'Message could not be sent.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit;
        }
```

and after that I have this:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {

        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }


     /*CLIENT MESSAGE*/


        echo 'Thank you for contacting us, one of our associates will contact you soon';

        }else {
            exit();

        }
```

I want to show that message in the same page of the form and reset the form.
Thanks in advance
Here is my form:

```
<form role="form" id="request_quoute" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/sfra/sendMail.php">                 
                    <input class="form-control col-xs-12" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>                    
                    <input class="form-control col-xs-12" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>                    
                    <textarea class="form-control col-xs-12" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="resize:none" required></textarea>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center">                
                    <button type="submit" id="send-form" class="btn btn-primary contact_button">Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Blank page is due to your mail body does not seems to have any data means $messaje must be empty so, try to print it and check.
Also post your form page code for further query.

Comment: no the message has the info and I receive the mail in my inbox with all of the data

Comment: This code is a mess and incomplete. It looks like a basic logic issue with your structure, but it's hard to tell. You also have two `send()` calls and entirely nonsensical exception handling.

Comment: the first send() is for sending the info in the form to my inbox and the second one is to answer to the user that his message was sent.